# Returning values from functions

Tags: shell, awk

I have a function which returns a version from first line of a file

```
checkVersion(){
Version=($(awk -F "|" '{print(substr($7,1,1))}' $1))    
echo "spark version $Version" 
return $Version
```

}

and used in if loop

```
if [ $(Version input.txt) == '1' ]
```

but it gives error stating too many arguments

Comment: You declare a function called `checkVersion` but your call is `Version` - is that an editing error or in the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` doesn't return value from a function, rather the status.

```
checkVersion(){
Version=($(awk -F "|" '{print(substr($7,1,1))}' $1))    
#echo "spark version $Version"
#return $Version
echo "$Version"
}
# and then...
if [ "$(checkVersion input.txt)" = '1' ]
.....
```

Comment: Yes that worked